# Pass object from ng-repeat when checkbox checked to array

Tags: angularjs

How can I pass the object tableSelection[{}]

I cannot find any way to do this without passing an index, which wont work in this case - I wish to just pass the object

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in grid.data" class="grid-row selectable">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-checklist-model="grid.tableSection" data-checklist-value="d"/> 
    </td>
```

This code won't pass the object to the array, which is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party library?

Comment: Table is <table smart-table-header="grid.config" style="margin-bottom:20px;">